# How to manipulate Android classes

Tags: android

New to Android.  Trying to find docs that show what Android classes expect to elicit changes. For example, to make a keyboard always visible, I could find some info searching Google, but not directly in the docs of the SDK.  Is there a source for more comprehensive docs on how Android works not just from the individual class level, but how it boots up and what to do to make small tweaks for an app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be what you're looking for, but here's some information on packages and classes

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/package-summary.html

I've been teaching myself Android for about a month now and the best reference I've found so far is the Android Developer site, especially under the References and Resources pages.

Hopefully that helps a little bit. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.